# keras embedding layer causing tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, embedding

here is the full stack

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 238, in <module>
    nnmodel.cnn(algo='cnnsubfeats')
  File "scripts.py", line 183, in cnn
    validation_split=vs
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/oea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1039, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/oea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 199, in fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/oea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/oea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2675, in _call
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/oea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1439, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/oea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[130,3006] = 22349 is not in [0, 12133)
         [[{{node embedding_1/embedding_lookup}} = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/Assign_2"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_1/embeddings/read, embedding_1/Cast, training/Adam/gradients/embedding_1/embedding_lookup_grad/concat/axis)]]
```

I tried extending the vocabulary size but i got the same error!

Comment: The error means that the index given to the embedding lookup is bigger than the size of your vocabulary. Test your dataset / data generation code. i.e. make sure that it generates the data that you expect. It is much cheaper to add tests to data generation code than try to guess why models with bad data do not work.

Comment: well I am using the embedding layer so if I set my max word to 3000 in the tokeniser how can I change my bow size before the embedding layer?

Comment: Most tokenisers have an option to specify the max vocabulary size. For instance the keras tokeniser has a num_words param which specifies that only the most common N tokens should be kept. It is also common to drop the top N most common tokens. For instance in English, often very common tokens (aka stopwords) such as "of", "a", "the" are dropped. That is however quite application specific. For instance the tokens "I" and "is" are relevant to some applications although they are very common.

Comment: yes I know that . the problem is i used the same code for another dataset and it worked perfectly my datashapes are similar so I do not understand why the embedding is giving this out of index error???

Comment: I can only repeat the recommendation to write test code explicitly for your generator before you feed the data in the model. I've lost countless hours attempting to train models with wrong data; and many failures are silent. In this case the code is telling you that the index in your model input is above the vocabulary size... 99.9% probability that the message is correct and your data generation is buggy.